# wagtail search_backend multilanguage

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-search

The wagtail docs say that PostgreSQL search is a good alternative for relative smaller websites. The docs show how to set the search backend.

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.contrib.postgres_search.backend',
        'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'english',
    }
}
```

[docs wagtail](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7/reference/contrib/postgres_search.html#language-postgresql-search-configuration)

However the website I'm creating has more then one language. How do I configure the other languages in the WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKEND?

Would 'SEARCH_CONFIG': ['english', 'dutch'] be possible? Docs don't say anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

Response to an old question, but maybe someone finds this useful as I just came across a need for this.

After your default (leave as fallback), create a backend config for each language using the language code.

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
        'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'english',
    },
    'en': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
        'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'english',
    },
    'nl': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
        'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'dutch',
    },
}
```

Now you can get your backend for current language from

```
from wagtail.search.backends import get_search_backend    
s = get_search_backend(backend=Locale.get_active().language_code)
```

These are the default languages in POSTGRES

```
$ psql -c "\dF"
```

Schema   |    Name    |              Description
------------+------------+---------------------------------------
pg_catalog | danish     | configuration for danish language
pg_catalog | dutch      | configuration for dutch language
pg_catalog | english    | configuration for english language
pg_catalog | finnish    | configuration for finnish language
pg_catalog | french     | configuration for french language
pg_catalog | german     | configuration for german language
pg_catalog | hungarian  | configuration for hungarian language
pg_catalog | italian    | configuration for italian language
pg_catalog | norwegian  | configuration for norwegian language
pg_catalog | portuguese | configuration for portuguese language
pg_catalog | romanian   | configuration for romanian language
pg_catalog | russian    | configuration for russian language
pg_catalog | simple     | simple configuration
pg_catalog | spanish    | configuration for spanish language
pg_catalog | swedish    | configuration for swedish language
pg_catalog | turkish    | configuration for turkish language

Answer (score 0):

I think I found howto. Would be nice if to see it confirmed.
Wagtail has this from wagtail.search.backends import get_search_backend

If you look at the source code you can see that you can define a backend when calling this function

s = get_search_backend(backend=default)

So you can switch backend on the fly by first calling this function and switch to some other backend on basis of the language.

Wagtail is so cool!